# Mapping RouteTable on PreInit() - Will it cause any problems?

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-4.0

My page route mapping changes depending on certain criteria. To determine this criteria I need access to `HttpRequest` which means I can't do my route mapping in `Application_Start()`. On that note I have done it on `PreInit()` on my default page and it seems to work without an issue. However, all the examples I have seen with Route Tables are doing it in Application_Start, is this purely to avoid clearing the route list and adding them again? Will there it cause any harm to my web application doing in the way I am doing it?

EDIT: Example:

I load controls from different folders based on the project number and whether the website is being viewed on a mobile device, on that note I need to know this information before mapping my routes, like so:

```
RouteCollection.MapPageRoute("OneParam", "{Action}.html", String.Format("~/{1}{2}/Default.aspx", ProjectNumber, MobilePathStr));
```

which would map to something like `~/1234/Mobile/Default.aspx` or could map to `~/1234/Default.aspx`.

Comment: That's not a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have added an example of what I am doing.

Comment: The route collection is global (shared) state.  That won't work.

Comment: Ah very valid point! I completely forgot about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that.

Instead, you should create your own `RouteBase` class which looks up that information for each request and runs the appropriate handler.

To send to an ASPX page, you can either `return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page;` or create a `PageRouteHandler` and delegate to it.